# Installing IbPy to be used in spyder (anaconda)

Tags: python, ibpy

I have installed Anaconda and currently using Spyder IDE.

I am trying to install a package (IbPy -> https://github.com/blampe/IbPy) so that it can be used in Spyder.

So far I tried pip install ibpy, as well as conda install ibpy, but without success since the package is not available in the anaconda repository where I would normally update and download the most common packages.

I have also tried to move the folder downloaded from GitHub to the correct site-packages folder of Anaconda (C:\Users\Username\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages), but still it does not work.

I also tried to run the setup.py (shift + right click on the folder, open new process here, Setup.py install), but without any success.

I tried to look for a solution everywhere, but I have had no luck so far.

If someone more tech savvy than me and practical with these specific could help, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install it from github. Use the following.

```
pip install https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/zipball/master
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a open terminal from the Anaconda Navigator and run the command:

```
conda install -c tibkiss ibpy2
```